# After decoding path URL code just stops, or so it seems

Tags: java, path

I try to get the `path` to the directory my class is in. That works fine. But I want to edit this path like this. Example:

Take this path:
`/C:/User/Folder1/bin/`

I want to change above path to this:
`C:\\User\\Folder1\\bin\\`

Now, I have written this code to accomplish this:

```
path = StartUp.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(path);
System.out.println(decodedPath);

pathArray = decodedPath.split("/");

pathLength = pathArray.length;
int x = 1;
while(x <= pathLength){
    goodPath = goodPath + pathArray[x] + "\\";
    x++;
}

System.out.println("goodPath " + goodPath);
System.out.println(decodedPath);
```

I thought this would accomplish it, but all output I get is:

```
/C:/User/Folder1/bin/
/C:/User/Folder1/bin/
5
```

For some reason it displays the number of elements in `pathArray` and skips the last two `System.out.println()`'s.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of an array out of bound exception.

Change

```
while(x <= pathLength){
```

with

```
while(x < pathLength){
```

In Java array indexes start from zero, therefore if an array is of lenght `L`, then the last item in the array has the index `L-1`. Therefore in your case you have to loop untile `x` is strictly smaller than `pathLength` (your array's length), and not smaller or equal to that. Otherwise in the last iteration variable `x` takes the value of `pathLength` and you will access an memory location of of the bounds of your array.

An additional annotations is that you start your loop with `x=1`, this is right in this case only because your original string start with the character `/`, and then the split function create an array where the first item (index zero) is an empty string, therefore is right to skip it by starting by index one.

Anyway, I suggest you also to take a look into the regular expressions, or easier in the method `replace` of the class `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like `(?<!^)\\/` and drop the first character. No need manually remove every forward slash. Or do the reverse drop the first character and replace the forward slashes eg.

```
String path = StartUp.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(path);
System.out.println(decodedPath);

Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("\\/");
Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(decodedPath.substring(1));
String replaceAll = matcher.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\");
System.out.println(replaceAll);
```